# Regex javascript remove negative percentage "-"

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I am in need of finding and removing the "-" negative sign in front of a percentage using either Regex or jQuery.

I've tried doing this:

```
$('[data-excel]').each(function() { 
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(' -', ' ')); 
});
```

But that doesn't seem to remove it. The reason why i have a space before the negative sign ** -** is there is a word in each that has it worded like *this-and* so it would pick up that one instead of the one that's the percentage on the page.

An example of what I am looking at:

> About -38% is made with this-and also with something else.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Using regedit? The Windows registry tool??

Comment: Regedit and regular expressions (regex) are two very different things.

Comment: Oops... getting my coding lang all mixed. Corrected. Thanks @ÁlvaroG.Vicario for pointing that out :)

Comment: What about (+/-)38% ? Because nothing is made up of a negative percentage of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myString.replace(/-(?=\d)/,"")
```

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look for a `-` followed by a digit.

http://regex101.com/r/rV3rF3/1

For completeness, to insure that the number is actually followed by a `%`, simply:

```
myString.replace(/-(?=d+%)/,"");
```

To account for (optional) decimals:

```
myString.replace(/-(?=\d+\.?\d*%)/,"");
```

Which matches:

```
-      literal -
?=     followed by (lookahead):
d+     1 or more digits
\.?    0 or 1 decimal point
d*     0 or more digits
```

http://regex101.com/r/rV3rF3/2

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the value is a percentage. This would turn "I scored -5 so now my average is -20% less than before" into "I scored 5 so now my average is 20% less than before".

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: True, but an easy fix (see vks' solution). The OP didn't state whether there are or are not other numbers in the string.

Comment: @MattBurland no other numbers are in the string. Just the percentage and text.

Comment: @StealthRT so there are no decimals? like `-13.5%`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Nope, not at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(?=\d+%)
```

Try this.This will look for the percentage sign after `-`.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/25

Comment: The question is vary vague, but percentage symbols are usually placed *after* numbers. A negative percentage would be `-5%`, for instance, not `-%5`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: `myStr.replace(/[/-]/g, '')`